# NextJS + NextAuth middleware not even being called after changing next.config

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, middleware, next-auth

I'm using `next-auth@4.18.7` & `next@13.1.1` and my middleware.ts stopped working suddenly after many changes I made. It seems not to be called in any way I have tried.

middleware.ts

```js
import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware";

export default withAuth({
  callbacks: {
    authorized({ req, token }) {
      const { pathname } = req.nextUrl;
      console.log(token, pathname); // this log never comes
      if (pathname.startsWith("/admin")) {
        return token?.roleLabel === "ADMIN" || token?.userRole === "admin";
      }
      // `/me` only requires the user to be logged in
      return !!token;
    },
  },
});

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/admin/:path*", "/c/:path*", "/me"],
};
```

next.config.js

```js
const { i18n } = require("./next-i18next.config");
const { PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER } = require("next/constants");

module.exports = (phase) => {
  let extensions = ['page.tsx', 'page.ts', 'page.jsx', 'page.js', 'api.ts', 'api.js']
  if (phase === PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER) extensions.push('doc.tsx')
  return {
    i18n,
    pageExtensions: extensions,
    images: {
      domains: ['domain.com'],
    },
  }
};
```

Should I rename my middleware.ts to middleware.page.ts? It doesn't make sense. I tried it and it didn't work. It's already in my root/ folder, I tried moving to pages/ but had no success.

Auth is working fine on React side but I can't intercept all my protected pages with this middleware. Please help D:

Answer (score 0):

I want to share my solution.

After trying a bunch of things, I found out that `next.config.js` custom page extensions were the reason behind the bug.

It seems like pageExtensions config counts middleware as pages, so after renaming it to `middleware.page.ts` or `middleware.api.ts` in my case made it work. I told you that it doesn't make sense, but actually it worked. I may have missed something when I was testing it before.

Just remind that `middleware` file has to be in the root folder.